# post_logout_redirect_uri ASP NET Core 2.2 AzureAD Razor Class Library RCL

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have tried using the sample
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/
Walked through the sample and all works.
We can't get it to redirect after logout process. Also, it seems the account controller is not there but it is called in _layout.chtml this must be something new.

Comment: I test the code sample you mentioned . It will redirect user to page shows "Which account do you want to sign out of?" . After choose one account , it will redirect back to the application .Do you modify the code sample or manually add Azure AD authetication to your .net core 2.2 app ?

Comment: You can also try to add logout url (http://localhost:xxxx/signout-callback-oidc) to allowed reply urls in your azure portal .

Comment: Yes, it does redirect to the application - what I'd like it to do is redirect to a different page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Yes, it does redirect to the application - what I'd like it to do is redirect to a different page.

You can redirect user to another page after sign-out by setting the `OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect` event :

1. In `Startup.cs` add `using System.Threading.Tasks;`
2. Config your new redirect url in `OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect` event :

   ```
   services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
   {
       options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

       options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;

       options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = (context) =>
       {

           context.Response.Redirect("/Home/About");
           context.HandleResponse();

           return Task.CompletedTask;
       };
   });
   ```

Comment: @twc , if that helps , you could mark as answer which may help others who meet same problem .

Comment: This worked but I had to remove the options.Authority line

Comment: @NanYu, thank you, this worked for me on Core 3.0. I want to understand the code better but I'm unable to find the `OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect` event in [OpenIdConnectHandler.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs) file. I'm curious how exactly did you know how to properly handle the event this way? I'd appreciate an explanation or some resources on what's going on in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The account controller code is built into the framework now.  You can see it in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.AzureAD.Controllers.Internal (see https://github.com/aspnet/AADIntegration/blob/0efa96de73e3235fbfc55cfe51d9547a693010cc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI/Areas/AzureAD/Controllers/AccountController.cs):

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.AzureAD.Controllers.Internal
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Area("AzureAD")]
    [NonController]
    [Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]
    internal class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public IOptionsMonitor<AzureADOptions> Options
        {
            get;
        }

        public AccountController(IOptionsMonitor<AzureADOptions> options)
        {
            this.Options = options;
        }

        [HttpGet("{scheme?}")]
        public IActionResult SignIn([FromRoute] string scheme)
        {
            scheme = scheme ?? AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            string str = base.Url.Content("~/");
            return this.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                RedirectUri = str
            }, new String[] { scheme });
        }

        [HttpGet("{scheme?}")]
        public IActionResult SignOut([FromRoute] string scheme)
        {
            scheme = scheme ?? AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            AzureADOptions azureADOption = this.Options.Get(scheme);
            string str = base.Url.Page("/Account/SignedOut", null, null, base.Request.Scheme);
            return this.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                RedirectUri = str
            }, new String[] { azureADOption.CookieSchemeName, azureADOption.OpenIdConnectSchemeName });
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have not be able to force a redirect after logout.  Instead, I see a page that says "You have successfully signed out."  I'd like to know how to redirect the user back to the Index page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#afs  When a view, partial view, or Razor Page is found in both the web app and the Razor Class Library, the Razor markup (.cshtml file) in the web app takes precedence. I guess I have to create a razor page to overide the RCL.

Answer (score 0):

I had to override the signedOut page manually by adding this to a controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut")]
    public IActionResult SignedOut()
    {
        return Redirect(<MyRealSignedOutRedirectUri>);
    }
```