# Custom authorization filter not working in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm working on adding authentication (and eventually authorization) with AzureAD to an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app using a custom authorization attribute filter. The code below implements the `IAuthorizationFilter`'s `OnAuthorization` method within which I redirect the user to the `SignIn` page when their authentication expires.

When a controller action with `[CustomAuthorizationFilter]` is hit I expect the attribute's `OnAuthorization` method to be hit right away whether or not the authentication cookie has expired.

That expectation doesn't happen and instead if a user is not authenticated and a controller action is hit, user is automatically reauthenticated with Microsoft and a valid cookie is created, and only then the `OnAuthorization` method is hit, defeating what I thought was the purpose of the `OnAuthorization` method.

I've been doing a lot of research to understand this behavior, but I'm clearly missing something. The most useful piece of information I found was in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0#authorization-iallowanonymous-removed-from-authorizationfiltercontextfilters):

> As of ASP.NET Core 3.0, MVC doesn't add AllowAnonymousFilters for
> [AllowAnonymous] attributes that were discovered on controllers and
> action methods. This change is addressed locally for derivatives of
> AuthorizeAttribute, but it's a breaking change for
> IAsyncAuthorizationFilter and IAuthorizationFilter implementations.

So, it appears that implementations with `IAuthorizationFilter` may be broken in 3.0+ and I don't know how to fix it.

Is this behavior normal or is my implementation incorrect?

If normal, why am I reauthenticated before the `OnAuthorization` method runs?

If incorrect, how can I implement it correctly?

CustomAuthorizationFilter.cs

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string signInPageUrl = "/UserAccess/SignIn";

        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult(new { redirectUrl = signInPageUrl });
                context.Result = jsonResult;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult(signInPageUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The IsAjaxRequest() extension used:

```
//Needed code equivalent of Request.IsAjaxRequest().
//Found this solution for ASP.NET Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282190/where-is-request-isajaxrequest-in-asp-net-core-mvc
//This is the one used in ASP.NET MVC 5: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AjaxRequestExtensions.cs
public static class AjaxRequestExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        if (request.Headers != null)
        {
            return (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

AzureAD authentication implementation in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IAppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
    Configuration.Bind("AppSettings", appSettings);

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options =>
        {
            options.Instance = appSettings.Authentication.Instance;
            options.Domain = appSettings.Authentication.Domain;
            options.TenantId = appSettings.Authentication.TenantId;
            options.ClientId = appSettings.Authentication.ClientId;
            options.CallbackPath = appSettings.Authentication.CallbackPath;
        });

    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/"; //Microsoft identity platform       
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469979/azure-ad-b2c-user-identity-name-is-null-but-user-identity-m-instance-claims9
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444747/user-identity-name-is-null-after-federated-azure-ad-login-with-aspnetcore-2-2
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/53918948/12300287
        options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/UserAccess/LogoutSuccess");
            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

    services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/UserAccess/NotAuthorized";
        options.LogoutPath = "/UserAccess/Logout";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(appSettings.Authentication.TimeoutInMinutes);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
        
    app.UseAuthentication(); // who are you?            
    app.UseAuthorization(); // are you allowed?

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=UserAccess}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue.

Comment: @GabrielCarvalho, don't know if you already figured something out, but I posted a solution I settled on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hoped to find a way to create an `AuthorizeAttribute` filter to solve this issue, but due to time constraints I settled on a regular action filter. It works with AJAX calls and it redirects the user to the appropriate pages if they are unauthorized or unauthenticated:

AjaxAuthorize action filter:

```
//custom AjaxAuthorize filter inherits from ActionFilterAttribute because there is an issue with 
//a inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute.
//post about issue: 
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017688/custom-authorization-filter-not-working-in-asp-net-core-3

//The statuses for AJAX calls are handled in InitializeGlobalAjaxEventHandlers JS function.

//While this filter was made to be used on actions that are called by AJAX, it can also handle
//authorization not called through AJAX.
//When using this filter always place it above any others as it is not guaranteed to run first.

//usage: [AjaxAuthorize(new[] {"RoleName", "AnotherRoleName"})]
public class AjaxAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string[] Roles { get; set; }

    public AjaxAuthorize(params string[] roles)
    {
        Roles = roles;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string signInPageUrl = "/UserAccess/SignIn";
        string notAuthorizedUrl = "/UserAccess/NotAuthorized";

        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (Roles.Length > 0)
            {
                bool userHasRole = false;
                foreach (var item in Roles)
                {
                    if (context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(item))
                    {
                        userHasRole = true;
                    }
                }
                if (userHasRole == false)
                {
                    if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {
                        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult(new { redirectUrl = notAuthorizedUrl });
                        context.Result = jsonResult;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        context.Result = new RedirectResult(notAuthorizedUrl);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult(new { redirectUrl = signInPageUrl });
                context.Result = jsonResult;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult(signInPageUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The IsAjaxRequest() extension used (reposted for a complete answer):

```
//Needed code equivalent of Request.IsAjaxRequest().
//Found this solution for ASP.NET Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282190/where-is-request-isajaxrequest-in-asp-net-core-mvc
//This is the one used in ASP.NET MVC 5: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AjaxRequestExtensions.cs
public static class AjaxRequestExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        if (request.Headers != null)
        {
            return (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

JavaScript ajax global error handler:

```
//global settings for the AJAX error handler. All AJAX error events are routed to this function.
function InitializeGlobalAjaxEventHandlers() {
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
        //these statuses are set in the [AjaxAuthorize] action filter
        if (xhr.status == 401 || xhr.status == 403) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
            window.location.replace(response.redirectUrl);
        } else {
           RedirectUserToErrorPage();
        }     
    });
}
```

Comment: This helped for my IAuthorizationFilter attribute class-based authorization as well. Thank You for the answer

Comment: But I had to make few changes to match my scenario.