# How to move custom authorization attribute policy implementation logic to startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I have implemented a custom `[Authorize]` attribute in a ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 app. The main reason I have a custom one is because the app uses a lot of AJAX and I couldn't figure out how to get it to work with AJAX. The attribute also implements `ActionFilterAttribute` instead of `IAuthorizationFilter` due to issues I posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64017688/12300287). Having this custom attribute means implementing my own logic to handle roles, which I did.

I've also implemented code to handle policies that group roles, but the code is inside the attribute itself. When a developer would think of changing policies within MVC framework, they'd probably think to go to `Startup.cs`.

How I could put the logic for policies in `Startup.cs` and have my custom attribute use it?

Custom attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeUser : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public Policies Policy { get; set; }

    public AuthorizeUser(Policies policy)
    {
        Policy = policy;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string signInPageUrl = "/UserAccess/Index";
        string notAuthorizedUrl = "/UserAccess/NotAuthorized";

        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            List<string> roles = GetRolesByPolicy(Policy);
            bool userHasRole = false;
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(role.ToUpper()))
                {
                    userHasRole = true;
                }
            }

            if (userHasRole == false)
            {
                if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult(new { redirectUrl = notAuthorizedUrl });
                    context.Result = jsonResult;
                }

                else
                {
                    context.Result = new RedirectResult(notAuthorizedUrl);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult(new { redirectUrl = signInPageUrl });
                context.Result = jsonResult;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult(signInPageUrl);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> GetRolesByPolicy(Policies policy)
    {
        List<RoleModel.Roles> roleEnums = new List<RoleModel.Roles>();
        roleEnums.Add(RoleModel.Roles.Admin); //admin is always allowed all actions
        switch (policy)
        {
            case Policies.EditUsers:
                roleEnums.AddRange(new List<RoleModel.Roles>
                {
                    RoleModel.Roles.User,
                    RoleModel.Roles.Customer,
                    RoleModel.Roles.Developer,
                    RoleModel.Roles.Manager
                });
                break;

            case Policies.ManageOrders:
                roleEnums.AddRange(new List<RoleModel.Roles>
                {
                    RoleModel.Roles.User,
                    RoleModel.Roles.Customer
                });
                break;

            case Policies.SendOrders:
                roleEnums.AddRange(new List<RoleModel.Roles>
                {
                    RoleModel.Roles.User
                });
                break;
        }

        return roleEnums.ConvertAll(r => r.ToString());
    }
}
```

Policies enum

```
public enum Policies
{
    EditUsers,
    ManageOrders,
    SendOrders
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to  put the logic for policies in Startup.cs,and then you can pass policy to AuthorizeUser custom ActionFilterAttribute?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. So the logic for policy is in `Startup.cs` and not in `AuthorizeUser` attribute.